# Como funciona Abstract States no angular

Tags: angularjs

Estou trabalhando em um APP e ainda estou conhecendo as funcionalidades do angular.

Tenho um arquivo de rotas e me foi sugerido adicionar o parâmetro `abstract: true` para impedir a navegação por url. Porém fui pesquisar mais sobre o mesmo e não entendi muito bem o que de fato ele faz.

Em nada do que eu li, diz que ele impede a navegação pela url. Então gostaria de saber qual é a real funcionalidade dessa propriedade?

Comment: AngularJS ou Angular2? São duas coisas distintas.

Comment: Pensei q fosse o mesmo. Mas no meu caso é para o angularjs. Vou editar!

Answer (score 2):

Um exemplo prático talvez ilustre algumas possibilidades.

Imagine que você possui uma aplicação onde acesso a um dado estado seja controlado por permissões - por exemplo, `#/usuarios` é um estado que exibe a lista de usuários, porém apenas usuários com permissão de administração pode vê-lo.

Você pode criar um estado abstrato - `acessoNegado`, por exemplo - que é invocado quando o estado `usuarios` é acessado sem as devidas permissões.

Assim, a URL presente no browser continua sendo `#usuarios`, porém o usuário está visualizando o conteúdo de `#acessoNegado`.

Comment: essa parte ficou clara pra mim agora. Mas esse acessoNegado seria uma variável de controle. Por exemplo: 'abstract: acessoNegado'?